# Fill out recipient tab before recipient has received envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I have a paper form that is being implemented in Docusign and must remain exactly as is. The problem I am running into is that there are fields on the form that must be filled out in stages.

Ie.

1. The form is sent to the first set of signers.
2. A field (tab) is filled with the date the envelope is being cc'ed to routing order 2 and then the envelope is cc'ed.
3. The envelope is paused until a later time in the internal process and the next form field is known.
4. The form field is filled in and the envelope is sent to the last set of signers.

When I tested this where no one had signed before filling in the tabs (which have the recipient id of the next person to sign) but the envelope had already been sent it worked fine.

The problem started when testing this where the first set of signers had already signed before entering information into the tab. When there are already signers the API returns the error `INVALID_TAB_OPERATION` with the message `The Tab specified is not valid for the requested operation.  Recipient not in state that allows correction.`

Here is my current code that fills in the tab. I have also tried updateDocumentTabs with no success. How can I do this?

```
$tabs = new Tabs([
    'text_tabs' => [
        new Text([
            'tab_id' => $employerReply->getTabId(),
            'value' => 'this is the employer reply.'
        ])
    ]
]);

$summary = $this->envelopesApi->updateTabs(
    config('private.docusign.account_id'),
    $envelopeId,
    '99',
    $tabs
);
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you want to programmatically change the tab values while the envelope is already in progress, is that right?
Note that this will require to use the "Correct" flow because envelopes that were already sent cannot be modified.

Comment: just a random idea - try to pause the envelope immediately following step 1 and do step 2 while the envelope is paused? not sure if that's allowed either, worth a shot...

Comment: Thanks. There is already a workflow setup to pause before routing order 2 and 3.

Comment: @InbarGazit If I try to manually correct the envelope in the Docusign UI, the document is locked with the error `Envelopes and documents are not editable if at least one recipient has completed an action.`. Are you saying this isn't going to be possible as we were told it would be?

Comment: are you doing it while the envelope is paused?

Comment: Yes the envelope is paused.

Comment: So it appears even when envelopes are paused you cannot modify them unless you use the correct flow. How are you trying to use "Correct" from the DocuSign UI? is this by the person that sent the envelope or an admin of the account? does the UI give you the menu option and then gives you the error when you attempt?